# Consistent NSUserDefaults saving

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

So in my app, I was saving some integer keys in `NSUserDefaults`,like around a minimum of 20.

Something like this but many:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"game1"];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"game2"];
[prefs setInteger:1 forKey:@"game3"];
```

So I was just wondering, should  **I call**:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

**Everytime I save?**

Because sometimes I'm experiencing an inconsistency of the integer I'm saving and have been loading either with stopping, running the app in `xCode` or from the Home Button.

I have read a couple of articles on a site that stated:

In iOS4, your User Defaults may not get saved when pressing the home button. Manually calling `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]` in `applicationDidEnterBackground:` should ensure that your `User Defaults` is saved correctly.

**Is this true and the same in iOS5?** Or are there more accurate ways, shorter ways of saving integers. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's documentation says this:

"Because this method is automatically invoked at periodic intervals, use this method only if you cannot wait for the automatic synchronization (for example, if your application is about to exit) or if you want to update the user defaults to what is on disk even though you have not made any changes."

So, depending on the urgency of the data you are settings, you may of may not need to call synchronize. Full documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Because im having problems sometimes, that when I set it again it would be okay but coming from the home button or exited from the xcode, it sometime isnt correct.

Comment: If the values aren't getting saved, then you need to call `-synchronize` every time they are changed. It is relatively low-overhead, as long as you aren't calling it many times per second.

Comment: So its bad calling `-synchronize` every now and then?

Comment: Not at all! `-synchronize` exists so that you can be sure your data are saved when you need them to be. There is absolutely nothing wrong with calling it.

Answer (score 0):

No you don't need to, when you call `setInteger:forKey:` on `prefs`, it automatically gets saved.

Comment: It doesn't save immediately though. '-synchronize' makes sure it's saved right away.

Comment: Yes that is true, but he asked if he should call `synchronize` every time he saves, which he shouldn't. It should only be used when needed and if the data is too important to lose if the app crashes.